# AngularJS - Need Help Understanding handlerequest and redirect after login

Tags: angularjs

I've been following a tutorial on thinkster to complete authorisation using JWTs.
I have it all working however there is one thing i do not understand fully:

The code:

```
function MainCtrl(user, auth) {
  var self = this;

  function handleRequest(res) {
    var token = res.data ? res.data.token : null;
    if(token) { console.log('JWT:', token); }
    self.message = res.data.message;
  }

  self.login = function() {
    user.login(self.username, self.password)
      .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me understanding what is actually happening in this line

```
.then(handleRequest, handleRequest)
```

namely what does this handleRequest, why is written twice like that?

Also, if after successful login, if i wanted to go to the homepage can i just add something like:

```
.success(){
    $location.path('/newValue')
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.login(self.username, self.password)` return a **promise** object,

**promise** has `.then(resolve,reject)` method,**resolve** means login success,**reject** means login fail.

in you case **resolve** and **reject** share the same function **handleRequest**

for more information about promise,you can refer [www.promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: I am following the same tutorial, but I do not seem to understand the part where it says `self.logout = function () {
        auth.logout && auth.logout()
    }`. Why is `auth.logout` being called twice.. both with and without brackets?